# Angularjs: Condition statement based on current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

There's something I've been stuck on for a couple days now. I would like to display an item based on the current user (id).

For an example:

```
<!-- if current user has already 'liked' this post -->
    Show 'UnLike' button
<!-- else -->
    Show 'Like' button
<!-- end -->
```

**How do you use conditional statements based on the current user's id in Angularjs?**

I'm using Rails as my backend along with Devise, if it helps..

Comment: begin to put data in js session

Comment: Hi @apneadiving, I'm new to Angularjs. Could you please elaborate or maybe type it as an answer. I've gone ahead and created a sessions controller since posting this. I can edit it in my question if you'd like? Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets make it easy.

First, [setup gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon).

At your Rails controller level, wherever needed, or in `before_filter` (`before_action` in Rails 4), do:

```
gon.current_user = { id: current_user.id }
```

then on Angular side:

```
app.service 'sessionService', [ '$window', ($window)->

  factory =
    current_user: ->
      $window.gon.current_user

  factory
]
```

Then inject you session service and you'll have access to the `current_user` object via the method

Answer (score 2):

If you want the "Angular way" of handling this on the client you may want to take a look at the [working CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IGoBJ) that I created.

The template:

```
<section ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ng-switch on="hasLiked">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-switch-when="true">Unlike</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-switch-when="false">Like</button>
  </ng-switch>
  <br>
  <button class="btn toggle" ng-click="hasLiked = !hasLiked" ng-bind-template="Change result of service call from '{{hasLiked}}' to '{{!hasLiked}}'">Change</button>
</section>
```

The javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('userSvc', function() {
  // mock $http lookup
  var lookupResult = true;

  return {
    hasLiked: lookupResult
  };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, userSvc) {
  $scope.hasLiked = userSvc.hasLiked;
});
```

Comment: The crux here though is the lookupResult method -- it still needs the current_user object from Rails, or at least some information regarding the current_user. I think you're right that it would be more "angular" to have that info be retrieved by a service rather than pulled directly from the session, *but* you still need to know the current user's ID (or some mechanism of identifying the user for the API) -- and @apneadiving's solution seems like a pretty good way to handle that.